# Compute digit-sums in specific columns of a data frame

Tags: r, vectorization, digits

I'm trying to sum the digits of integers in the last 2 columns of my data frame.  I have found a function that does the summing, but I think I may have an issue with applying the function - not sure?

```
Dataframe
a = c("a", "b", "c")
b = c(1, 11, 2)
c = c(2, 4, 23)
data <- data.frame(a,b,c)

#Digitsum function
digitsum <- function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(as.character(x)) - 1))) %% 10)

#Applying function
data[2:3] <- lapply(data[2:3], digitsum)
```

This is the error that I get:

```
*Warning messages:
1: In 0:(nchar(as.character(x)) - 1) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: In 0:(nchar(as.character(x)) - 1) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `digitsum` at the moment works fine for a single scalar input, for example,

```
digitsum(32)
# [1] 5
```

But, it can not take a vector input, otherwise `":"` will complain. You need to vectorize this function, using `Vectorize`:

```
vec_digitsum <- Vectorize(digitsum)
```

Then it works for a vector input:

```
b = c(1, 11, 2)
vec_digitsum(b)
# [1] 1 2 2
```

Now you can use `lapply` without trouble.

Answer (score 2):

@Zheyuan Li 's answer solved your problem of using `lapply`. Though I'd like to add several points:

- `Vectorize` is just a wrapper with `mapply`, which doesn't give you the performance of vectorization.
- The function itself can be improved for much better readability:

see

```
digitsum <- function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(as.character(x)) - 1))) %% 10)
vec_digitsum <- Vectorize(digitsum)

sumdigits <- function(x){
  digits <- strsplit(as.character(x), "")[[1]]
  sum(as.numeric(digits))
}
vec_sumdigits <- Vectorize(sumdigits)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(digitsum(12324255231323),
  sumdigits(12324255231323), times = 100)

Unit: microseconds
                      expr    min     lq     mean median     uq    max neval cld
  digitsum(12324255231323) 12.223 12.712 14.50613 13.201 13.690 96.801   100   a
 sumdigits(12324255231323) 13.689 14.667 15.32743 14.668 15.157 38.134   100   a
```

The performance of two versions are similar, but the 2nd one is much easier to understand.

Interestingly, the `Vectorize` wrapper add considerable overhead for single input:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(vec_digitsum(12324255231323), 
  vec_sumdigits(12324255231323), times = 100)

Unit: microseconds
                          expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq      max neval cld
  vec_digitsum(12324255231323) 92.890 96.801 267.2665 100.223 108.045 16387.07   100   a
 vec_sumdigits(12324255231323) 94.357 98.757 106.2705 101.445 107.556   286.00   100   a
```

Another advantage of this function is that if you have really big numbers in string format, it will still work (with small modification of removing the `as.character`). While the first version function will have problem with big numbers or may introduce errors.

Note: At first my benchmark was comparing the vectorized version of OP function and non-vectorized version of my function, that gave me the wrong impression of my function is much faster. Turned out that was caused by `Vectorize` overhead.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate your help!